# Google Glass Mirror API service is not available

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

A few hours ago the API and demo app were released, but when going to the Google API services page, the [mirror API](https://code.google.com/apis/console) is not listed yet.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about?https://developers.google.com/glass/about

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=2

Comment: Look this : https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=2